# How to convert $\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$ into rectangular form

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

**Question**

How to convert $\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$ into rectangular form?

I know that tan=$x/y$ but in that case this would be useless and I was wondering how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by `convert into rectangular form`? FWIW $\alpha= \arctan(4/3)$ is not a "nice" value (though $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\alpha)$ *are*).

Comment: Do you actually have the polar *equation* $\theta = \arctan(4/3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polar equation

$$ \theta=\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$$

may be converted into a rectangular equation as follows:

1. $\tan\theta=\dfrac{4}{3}$
2. $\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\dfrac{4}{3}$
3. $3\sin\theta=4\cos\theta$
4. $3r\sin\theta=4r\cos\theta$
5. $3y=4x$
6. $y=\dfrac{4}{3}x$

Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

What is the *rectangular form* of a number? Anyway,
$$ \arctan\frac{4}{3}=\arcsin\frac{4}{5}=\arccos\frac{3}{5} $$
is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, by the following well-known lemma:
$$ q\in\mathbb{Q},\;\cos(\pi q)\in\mathbb{Q}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \cos(\pi q)\in\left\{-1,-\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},1\right\}.$$
Numerically, $\arctan\frac{4}{3}\approx 53^\circ 7'48''$.